# Sending out transactional emails manually

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I need to send out an email to al my customers, i have created a transactional email template which has all the relevant information in it but i do not know how to send this emails to registered customer, can anyone help?

So my question is how can you manually send emails to customers?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may need to tinker with some codes to achieve this.

There's a fairly old blog post by Inchoo which detailed the steps to do this:

- http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-custom-emails/

There's two newer blog posts about it here:

- http://www.techflirt.com/magento-send-custom-email/
- http://navaneeth.me/send-email-using-email-template-in-magento-manually/

If you don't want to tinker with codes, one easy way is to export your client lists to a third-party mailing provider like MailChimp:

- https://connect.mailchimp.com/integrations/magento

You can then send out emails to your clients directly within MailChimp.

Comment: I like the mailchimp idea as we already use mailchimp for our newsletters. in the email it has varibles for example there names, email address and customer numbers. Do you know if that would all still work using mailchimp?

Comment: I don't think the default Magento variables will work. You'll need to replace them with MailChimp's variables.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    $sender  = array(
        'name' => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/name', $storeId),
        'email' => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/email', $storeId)
    );
     $vars = array(
    'item_html' => $item_html,
    );
    $templateId = 2;
    Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $email_id , '', $vars, $storeId);
```

Comment: where would i put this code? just a .php file then put it in my root?

Comment: When do you want to sent the email. Is it like a CRON?

Comment: no once we have transferred our customer database we need to send out the email directing the user to a page where they can create a new password.

Comment: Then you can just put it in your root and call it once. Just make sure you load the Mage class using `require_once "../app/Mage.php";` and set the store .

Comment: It looks like sendTransactional() ingores the css file from the email template?

Comment: @xxx Sorry man, I do not remember and it's been a while since I have worked in Magento. I think you can get the answer by checking the sendTransactional function in core/email_template model.

Comment: I found it out. It must uses ->setDesignConfig to include the CSS files

Answer (score 0):

you have to first create a template at backend and pass required parameters into it 
you can find your code here

https://codexcellence.wordpress.com/2015/09/27/sending-emails-in-magento/

Comment: it sounds like a good instruction, but the link is not available